# yet another Access-sql-multiple-joins predicament

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010

Access 2010

This works great:

```
SELECT aa.recid,
       aa.account_clid,
       bb.code AS type,
       aa.number,
       aa.company,
       aa.product,
       aa.status
FROM  (  [account] AS aa
RIGHT JOIN [account_types] AS bb ON aa.[type]    = bb.[account_code]  )
```

while this, infuriatingly, throws the infamous "JOIN expression not supported" msg

```
SELECT aa.recid,
       aa.account_clid,
       bb.code AS type,
       aa.number,
       aa.company,
       aa.product,
       aa.status,
       cc.code AS stattus
FROM  (  [account] AS aa
RIGHT JOIN [account_types] AS bb ON aa.[type]    = bb.[account_code]  )
RIGHT JOIN [account_codes] AS cc ON aa.[status2] = cc.[account_code]
```

Would someone be so kind as to tell me what I ( or Access) is doing wrong?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I should be using LEFT JOINs instead of RIGHT JOINs.

Thanks all,

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve

Comment: "Would someone be so kind as to tell me what I ( or Access) is doing wrong?" - I was so tempted to say "Using Access"...